# ExtendedPetriNets Library Problem in OpenModelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica, petri-net

I am new to openmodelica,
Since I work in reliability engineering, the main feature of openmodelica that I will use is petri nets modelling.
I've learnt the ExtendedPetriNets library (https://github.com/modelica-3rdparty/ExtendedPetriNets). 
However when I open this library in openmodelica I received several error messages which can be grouped into:

1. Class or component Ellipse not found

`In modifier (Ellipse(extent = {{-100, -100}, {100, 100}}), class or component extent), class or component Ellipse not found in <Icon>`

2. Duplicate modification of element Line.points on component Icon

`[ExtendedPetriNets: 569:14-569:42]: Duplicate modification of element Line.points on component Icon`

I suspect these error messages are due to version incompatibility between ExtendedPetriNets V 1.0 and OmEdit v1.13.2. 
Hence my questions are:
1. Is it really due to version problem?
2. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is due to version problems.

But the errors above are not important and you could just remove the problematic code, since `Ellipse` and `Line.points` are just part of the graphics.
ExtendedPetriNets uses an older set of graphical annotations than the one standardized in Modelica Specification 3.

However, ExtendedPetriNets also rely on ModelicaAdditions.PetriNets from https://github.com/modelica-deprecated/ModelicaAdditions which uses an older version of the Modelica Standard Library - and you would need conversions to use that with current versions.

It is likely that this will create more severe problems if you solve the first ones.

In the new Modelica Standard Library there is sort of a replacement for petri nets in the form of Modelica.StateGraph but it seems to lack the extensions you need.

Comment: As a remark: PNlib is a more modern PetriNet library, so I would suggest trying it: https://github.com/lochel/PNlib